# How can I move camera in matter.js

Tags: matter.js

How can I move the camera to a specific position in matter.js?

I want the camera to follow my main character.

I tried this tutorial: http://brm.io/matter-js/demo/#views
but truth be told, I did not understand it.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what you're trying to do? Are you creating a side-scroller game?

Comment: Yeap, I`m trying to make the camere fallow a character, just like in Mario World

Comment: whoever upvoted this question: there is no question.

Comment: Example with p5: https://github.com/b-g/p5-matter-examples/blob/master/6-camera-follow-canvas/sketch.js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found how to make it: http://codepen.io/vanuatu/pen/VeQMpp

We need to control render bounds, like this:

```
//
hero = bubbleBall

// Follow Hero at X-axis
engine.render.bounds.min.x = centerX + hero.bounds.min.x
engine.render.bounds.max.x = centerX + hero.bounds.min.x + initialEngineBoundsMaxX

// Follow Hero at Y-axis
engine.render.bounds.min.y = centerY + hero.bounds.min.y
engine.render.bounds.max.y = centerY + hero.bounds.min.y + initialEngineBoundsMaxY

// Update Mouse
Mouse.setOffset(mouseConstraint.mouse, engine.render.bounds.min);
```

I hope that can help someone

Answer (score 2):

An easier way to do it:

```
Render.lookAt(render, player, {
  x: 1080,
  y: 1920
});
```

x and y are the width and height of the render bounds.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's start with this simple example :

```
     // module aliases
        var Engine = Matter.Engine,
            Render = Matter.Render,
            World  = Matter.World,
            Runner = Matter.Runner,
            Bodies = Matter.Bodies;

        var engine = Engine.create();
        var runner = Runner.create();

        // create a renderer
        var render = Render.create({
            element: document.body,  
            engine: engine,
            runner: runner,
            options: {
                    width: 1280,
                    height: 720
                }
        });

        var vertices = [{ x :  50, y :   0},
                        { x :  63, y :  38},
                        { x : 100, y :  38},
                        { x :  69, y :  59},
                        { x :  82, y : 100},
                        { x :  50, y :  75},
                        { x :  18, y : 100},
                        { x :  31, y :  59},
                        { x :   0, y :  38},
                        { x :  37, y :  38} ];

        // add a star at center
        var star = Matter.Vertices.create(vertices);
        var starBody = Bodies.fromVertices(640, 360, star, {isStatic: true}, true);

        // add all of the bodies to the world
        World.add(engine.world, [ starBody]);

        Render.run(render); 
        Runner.run(runner, engine);
```

You should see a little star at center, if you want to move the camera, your render needs to have bounds, modify the render instanciation as follow :

```
<pre><code>

    var render = Render.create({
        element: document.body,  
        engine: engine,
        runner: runner,
        options: {
                  width: 1280,
                  height: 720,
                   <b>hasBounds : true</b>
                 }
    });
```

And use the `Bounds` module alias :

```
    var Engine = Matter.Engine,
        Render = Matter.Render,
        World  = Matter.World,
        Runner = Matter.Runner,
        Bodies = Matter.Bodies,
        Bounds = Matter.Bounds;
```

Now you can translate the bounds of your render to move your camera :

```
    let translate = {x : -100, y : -100}
    Bounds.translate(render.bounds, translate);
```

What it does in fact is something like this :

```
    function moveMatterJSCamera(offsetX, offsetY) {
                render.bounds.min.x += offsetX;
                render.bounds.max.x += offsetX;
                render.bounds.min.y += offsetY;
                render.bounds.max.y += offsetY;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that translating everything works too. like  `transX=-player.position.x` and then doing     `Matter.Body.translate(body,{x:transX,y:0})` with all your bodies including the player

Answer (score 0):

```
function track(){
  Render.lookAt(render, player, {
    x: 500,
    y: 500
  });
}

function repeatOften() {
  track()
  requestAnimationFrame(repeatOften);
}
requestAnimationFrame(repeatOften);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.