# translate view in matter.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js, matter.js

I'm trying to make a simple sidescroller, extending [this tutorial](https://thecodingtrain.com/challenges/138-angry-birds-with-matterjs).

It uses Matter.js and p5.js

To move left and right, I'm getting the mouseWheel delta.

```
  translateX += event.delta;
```

From there in the drawing function I can call

```
translate(translateX, 0);
```

This moves all of my p5.js drawings.  The problem is, how do I tell Matter.js?  All my interactions are off now by the delta.  The boxes are now 100px to the right, but the interactions are in the original location.

I tried using  [World.translate](http://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/World.html#method_translate)  but it seemed like it was moving the bodies oddly and not moving the constraints at all.  Maybe it's the wrong approach.

Comment: [Rotate Camera in Matter.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65462243/6243352) shows how to do a top-down all-direction viewport. Adjusting the viewport to a sidescroller is mostly a matter of changing the physics behavior to suit your needs.

Comment: Also related: [How can I move camera in matter.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34913835/how-can-i-move-camera-in-matter-js) and https://github.com/b-g/p5-matter-examples/blob/master/6-camera-follow-canvas/sketch.js